# sharepoint copy a list to a different web

Tags: sharepoint, stsadm

how can i copy a sharepoint list with all its data to a different web?

is there an stsadm command to do this?

or even through the gui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do this with Gary [LaPointe's stsadm extensions](http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2007/08/stsadm-commands_09.html). They're pretty sweet. Specifically, look into the [`gl-copylist` command](http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2007/09/importexportcopy-lists.html).

Answer (score 5):

What you can do is Save that List as Template with the contents included and create a List Based on the save template.

To Save the List as Template you need to navigate to the List Settings Page and Select Save as Template, check the "include content" check box. Enter a Name for the template and say Okay. Next time when you try to create the list you will see the saved template and you can create list using that.

You can also take that saved template from the List Template Gallery and add it to different application / site collection.