# Moving Lists in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

Does anyone know how I can move a list from one sub site to another, but retaining all content, including version history?

Saving as a template doesn't work, I'm not able to use sitemanager.aspx, as my company has a policy to have Publishing Infrastructure de-activated.

Any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate, as answers already exist: - [SharePoint 2007: Possible to copy a list instance from 1 server to another without using a feature?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667568/sharepoint-2007-possible-to-copy-a-list-instance-from-1-server-to-another-withou) - [sharepoint copy a list to a different web](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378553/sharepoint-copy-a-list-to-a-different-web)

Comment: please check this...
http://grounding.co.za/blogs/neil/archive/2008/10/05/moving-a-list-with-content-between-sharepoint-servers.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please do this which is the most effective way to get your requirements done.

[geekswithblogs.net/AnneBougie/archive/2009/01/23/copy-a-sharepoint-list.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20200925093703/http://geekswithblogs.net/AnneBougie/archive/2009/01/23/copy-a-sharepoint-list.aspx)

[geekswithblogs.net/AnneBougie/archive/2009/03/15/part-2-copy-a-sharepoint-list-programmatically.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20200225095506/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/AnneBougie/archive/2009/03/15/part-2-copy-a-sharepoint-list-programmatically.aspx)

Just create a web part that can sit on the site with two controls where a user can type in a list name and press a button and inside the web part code you can copy and paste the list with exactly same contents to a required location.

Hope this helps you..